# Provider token per Bundle ID?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, node-apn

Is it possible to use one provider token for two different apps, belong to the same account / team?

Server sends push notification to APNS but for second Bundle ID receives error:

```
status: '400',
response: { reason: 'TopicDisallowed' } } ]
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I'm having same issue and there doesn't seem to be much content with solutions.